# PHP codeigniter, how do I make different key in the url so it will call to different controller name instead of the actual controller name?

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, routes, controller

lets say my url is:

http://www.mysite.com/controller1/

I want to make routing so it wont look for the controller1, it will search for controller1 as the key.

so I will have a key like array for the controllers

```
<?php
$controllers_mapArr = array(
   'controller1'=>'actual_controler_name',
);

?>
```

it will execute the value of the controller key 'actual_controler_name' but the URL will show controller1
any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can **easily** do this using codeigniter's routing functionality, you have to add rules in `application/config/routes.php` file, following are the examples for doing

```
$route['journals'] = "blogs";
```

if your url is like http://example.com/journals then your URL will call blogs controller

```
$route['journals/joe'] = "blogs/users/34";
```

using this rule your if you access your url http://example.com/journals/joe then it will call blogs controller's users method with 34 as a value for function argument.

check the [detailed document](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html) or routing here : http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html

Answer (score 0):

Ok found the answer with a littel help from my friend actually is one of the basics in codeigniter
any way there is the answer:
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html